# Android IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, eclipse, exception, arraylist, stack-trace

I keep getting an IllegalArgumentException when the following method is ran:

```
public int randomize(ArrayList<Integer> list){
    Random rdm = new Random();  
    int size = list.size(); 
    int chosen = rdm.nextInt(size);
    Integer card = list.get(chosen);
    list.remove(chosen);
    return card;
}
```

Here is the StackTrace:

```
11-22 16:52:16.890: E/AndroidRuntime(24979): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-22 16:52:16.890: E/AndroidRuntime(24979): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.marshall.meadows182.match/edu.marshall.meadows182.match.Match}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
11-22 16:52:16.890: E/AndroidRuntime(24979):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1821)
11-22 16:52:16.890: E/AndroidRuntime(24979):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1842)
11-22 16:52:16.890: E/AndroidRuntime(24979):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
11-22 16:52:16.890: E/AndroidRuntime(24979):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
11-22 16:52:16.890: E/AndroidRuntime(24979):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-22 16:52:16.890: E/AndroidRuntime(24979):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
11-22 16:52:16.890: E/AndroidRuntime(24979):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
11-22 16:52:16.890: E/AndroidRuntime(24979):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 16:52:16.890: E/AndroidRuntime(24979):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-22 16:52:16.890: E/AndroidRuntime(24979):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-22 16:52:16.890: E/AndroidRuntime(24979):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-22 16:52:16.890: E/AndroidRuntime(24979):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-22 16:52:16.890: E/AndroidRuntime(24979): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
11-22 16:52:16.890: E/AndroidRuntime(24979):    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:186)
11-22 16:52:16.890: E/AndroidRuntime(24979):    at edu.marshall.meadows182.match.Match.randomize(Match.java:200)
11-22 16:52:16.890: E/AndroidRuntime(24979):    at edu.marshall.meadows182.match.Match.initArrays(Match.java:108)
11-22 16:52:16.890: E/AndroidRuntime(24979):    at edu.marshall.meadows182.match.Match.onCreate(Match.java:218)
11-22 16:52:16.890: E/AndroidRuntime(24979):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
11-22 16:52:16.890: E/AndroidRuntime(24979):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1785)
11-22 16:52:16.890: E/AndroidRuntime(24979):    ... 11 more
```

The ArrayLists that I am passing through do have elements in them (or they pass through a method that should put them in there) Anyone know why this is?

Comment: Please paste the full code along with your onCreate(). We need some context to try to understand how this could be causing Android-specific, Activity issues.

Comment: @LuxuryMode the stacktrace shows the error with the `nextInt` method on the random object, no need for further context.

Comment: @QuintinRobinson, thanks I missed that.

Answer (score 6):

From [javadoc:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29)

> public int nextInt(int n)
>
> Throws:
>
> ```
>    IllegalArgumentException - n is not positive.
> ```

EDIT: I try with this code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Random r = new Random();

    System.out.println(r.nextInt(0)); // <-- error
    // It cannot return a value between 0 (inclusive) and... 0 (exclusive!!!)
}
```

The output is an IllegalArgumentExcepion:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive
    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at Random0.main(Random0.java:7)
```

If your list is empty, your variable size may be 0, that is not positive.
You must catch this particular case, and manage it.

Comment: Tested with a simple case: `int foo = rdm.nextInt(0);` --> same crash.

Comment: Stupid Java, cannot even create a random in the range [0..0] :)

Comment: @comead - positive doesn't mean "not negative". It means greater than zero.

Comment: the list is populated. before the random generator is called, the lists are being populated.

Comment: yea, I know that the issue lies with the random generator and the list.size(), but it doesnt make sense.

Comment: what a weird behavior, I ended putting a `catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { continue; }`